# Clicking title won't show its answer (frequenty asked questions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this.faqLogic = function()
{
    $('a .toggle').click(function(){
        $('this .answer').show();
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<li class="clearfix question">
    <a class="toggle" href="#">>
        <h3>
            QUESTION
        </h3>
    </a>
    <div id="answer_1" class="answer">
        <h6>
            <span>ANSWER</span>
        </h6>
    </div>
</li>
```

There are multiple questions/answers of course. I just cant understand as to why it won't work at all. I'm getting no errors and required dependencies (jquery) are installed and called in first.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://flukeout.github.io/ A good way to learn CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to select elements of class `.answer` that are children of a `<this>` element. Clearly you have no `<this>` element.

Also, because you have a space between `a .toggle`, you're selecting elements of class `.toggle` that are *children* of an `a` element. You want `a` element that have class `.toggle`. No space for that selector, so it would be `a.toggle`.

All in all, perhaps you meant:

```
$('a.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.answer').show();
});
```

I suggest that you take a read of how CSS selectors work in general. Your understanding could do with a bit of firming-up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clearfix question">
    <a class="toggle" href="#">
        <h3>
            QUESTION
        </h3>
    </a>
    <div id="answer_1" class="answer">
        <h6>
            <span>ANSWER</span>
        </h6>
    </div>
</li>
```